# Error report - ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, no-data

I'm getting this error:

Error report -
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqq9b.png)

I created a new tablespace HR from HR Schema and I'm able to create tables, however, they do not show at the objects tab in Toad. I cannot insert anything into tables I created and the tables of HR Schema.
The data in the tables of Schema isn't showing as well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlvIN.png)

I tried this:
ALTER USER  quota unlimited on ;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmSzC.png)

Still, I am getting error's as:

Error starting at line : 19 in command -
ALTER USER hr quota unlimited on users
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A49pp.png)

Help me, to solve this Error
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Based on screenshots you posted, it seems you didn't pay attention to **output** of commands you ran. All of them ended up with **insufficient privileges**.

It means that you can't perform those `alter user` *this and that* when you're connected as current user - they have to be performed by a **privileged user** (such as `SYS`, if you don't have any other with appropriate DBA privileges).

Therefore: connect as `SYS` and re-run command you used to grant privileges to `hr`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new to this, your answer helped me.

The Grant is Succeeded, still, I cannot insert anything into tables that I created and the tables of HR Schema. The data in the tables of Schema isn't showing as well.

Comment: What does it mean, that you can not insert anything? Are you - now - connected as HR user? As table **owner**, you have ALL privileges on your objects (without any additional grants from SYS user), so INSERT should work (as well as UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT).

Comment: I have Edited my Question, Can you Help me Sort it out. @littlefoot